# Gradle-plugins : how can i know Gradle supported plugins version

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, gradle-plugin

I am trying to install sonarqube plugin in my gradle project.

I am using

**Gradle 3.5**

Groovy:       2.4.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_171 (Oracle Corporation 25.171-b11)
OS:           Linux 4.4.0-128-generic amd64

And in build.gradle I added:

```
plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.0.1"
}
```

I run `gradle sonarqube` command
I am getting error like this,

```
* What went wrong:
org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.getRuntimeJar()Ljava/io/File;

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.getRuntimeJar()Ljava/io/File;
        at org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubePlugin.getLibraries(SonarQubePlugin.java:363)
```

How can I know which version of sonarqube I should mention for Gradle 3.5?

Comment: Why not trying to use the most recent versions of the SonarQube plugin?

Comment: See also [here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-gradle). The latest release is 2.6.2; you need SonarQube 6.7 for that.